# Force Spring context reload before test

Tags: java, spring, junit

Is there a way to force the full rebuild of Spring context **before** the test?
Marking it with @DirtiesContext does not affect current test.
WHY: Cause before the test I set some System properties, that influence the context during build.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't think so.

I haven't tried this, but one workaround might be to obtain the context in the `@Before` or `@BeforeClass` method, and call reload.

Your test should obtain the context (and cast it to `ConfigurableApplicationContext`), by following the test context guidance in the [Spring Framework Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-support-classes).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to do this... But I warn you, it **is dirty!**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { .... })
// order of test methods is important!
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class MyTest {
  static {
    System.setProperty("myprop", "myvalue");
  }

  /**
   * Fake test that forces spring to reload context before real tests.
   */
  @Test
  @DirtiesContext
  public void aaReloadContext() {

  }

  /**
   * Fake test that clears system property after tests.
   */
  @Test
  public void zzClearProperty() {

    System.clearProperty("myprop");
  }

  ... real test methods...
```